# Excel Macro to Merge Rows using Multiple Criteria

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with a huge Excel worksheet and I am a total programming/macro newbie.  I am hoping someone out there can show me a macro that might be able to help me as I am in a time crunch and I don't know how I'll get this done manually.  The spreadsheet contains transaction data related to employees' retirement amounts for a particular Pay Date.  I need to find a way to do merge rows based on multiple criteria.  For example IF the Emp_ID and Trans_Type match, THEN the amounts for the Emp_Contrib and Empr_Contrib should be added together and the extra row(s) deleted, thereby "merging" the rows.  Also, if there are rows where Emp_ID match and there are rows with multiple Trans_Type listed, the same transaction types that are similar should be merged together and the Emp_Contrib and Empr_Contrib should be added together.

Basically it should merge Emp_Contrib and Empr_Contrib for an employee when the transaction types are the same.  If an employee has multiple rows with multiple transaction types, then merge similar transaction types.  I am probably not explaining this well, so please see below...

Here's an example of the BEFORE (fake data of course)...

```
Emp_ID  PayDate Check_Num   Trans_Type  Fund_Desc   Emp_Contrib Empr_Contrib
2222    1/30/2015   145511  5000        Retirement  300         0
2222    1/30/2015   145511  5000        Retirement  0           52.5
4444    1/30/2015   145522  6000        Roth        1894        0
4444    1/30/2015   145522  6000        Roth        0           52.5
4444    1/30/2015   145522  7000        457         1894        0
4444    1/30/2015   145522  7000        457         26.25       0
4444    1/30/2015   145522  8000        401K        100         0
4444    1/30/2015   145522  8000        401K        0           50
```

And here's what I need for the AFTER...

```
Emp_ID  PayDate Check_Num   Trans_Type  Fund_Desc   Emp_Contrib Empr_Contrib
2222    1/30/2015   145511  5000        Retirement  300         52.5
4444    1/30/2015   145522  6000        Roth        1894        52.5
4444    1/30/2015   145522  7000        457         1920.25     0
4444    1/30/2015   145522  8000        401K        100         50
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

-Chris

Answer (score 1):

To get only unique rows, do the following:

1. Select the columns Emp_ID, PayDate, Check_Num, Trans_Type, and Fund_Desc
2. Go to the Data tab -> Advanced Filter
3. In the Advanced Filter dialog, select "Copy to another location" and check the "Unique records only" checkbox
4. Select somewhere to copy the unique records to, I just selected cell I1

This is what it looks like:

[image: how to advanced filter]

After performing the Advanced Filter, this is what it should look like:

[image: After advanced filter]

Now you can just use `SUMIFS` formulas to get the numbers added up and displayed with unique rows data.  Using my suggested location (though you can adjust to your preferred location):

- In cell N2 (for Emp_Contrib) use this formula and copy down: `=SUMIFS(F:F,A:A,I2,B:B,J2,C:C,K2,D:D,L2,E:E,M2)`
- In cell O2 (for Empr_Contrib) use this formula and copy down: `=SUMIFS(G:G,A:A,I2,B:B,J2,C:C,K2,D:D,L2,E:E,M2)`

That should provide your desired results.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a macro to do the above.

First, Insert a Class Module; rename it `cContributions`.

Then, Insert a Regular Module.

In the Regular Module, adjust the Worksheet Names (wsSrc and wsRes) to reflect your real sheet names; and rRes to reflect the upper left corner where you want the results written.

Note that we use a combination of Employee ID and Transaction type to create a Unique Key to combine.  If your source table included multiple dates, and you wanted to also segregate by Dates, all you would have to do is add PayDate to the key.

### Class Module

```
'RENAME Me cContributions
Option Explicit
Private pEmp_ID As String
Private pPayDate As Date
Private pCheck_Num As Long
Private pTrans_Type As String
Private pFund_Desc As String
Private pEmp_Contrib As Currency
Private pEmpr_Contrib As Currency

Public Property Get Emp_ID() As String
    Emp_ID = pEmp_ID
End Property
Public Property Let Emp_ID(Value As String)
    pEmp_ID = Value
End Property

Public Property Get PayDate() As Date
    PayDate = pPayDate
End Property
Public Property Let PayDate(Value As Date)
    pPayDate = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Check_Num() As Long
    Check_Num = pCheck_Num
End Property
Public Property Let Check_Num(Value As Long)
    pCheck_Num = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Trans_Type() As String
    Trans_Type = pTrans_Type
End Property
Public Property Let Trans_Type(Value As String)
    pTrans_Type = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Fund_Desc() As String
    Fund_Desc = pFund_Desc
End Property
Public Property Let Fund_Desc(Value As String)
    pFund_Desc = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Emp_Contrib() As Currency
    Emp_Contrib = pEmp_Contrib
End Property
Public Property Let Emp_Contrib(Value As Currency)
    pEmp_Contrib = Value
End Property

Public Property Get Empr_Contrib() As Currency
    Empr_Contrib = pEmpr_Contrib
End Property
Public Property Let Empr_Contrib(Value As Currency)
    pEmpr_Contrib = Value
End Property
```

### Regular Module

```
Option Explicit
Sub CombineContributions()
    Dim cC As cContributions, colC As Collection
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet, rRes As Range
    Dim vSrc As Variant, vRes() As Variant
    Dim I As Long
    Dim sKey As String

Set wsSrc = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set wsRes = Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set rRes = Range("I1")

'Get source data
With wsSrc
    vSrc = .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp)).Resize(COLUMNSIZE:=7)
End With

'Collect data and combine as required
Set colC = New Collection
On Error Resume Next 'to detect combos
For I = 2 To UBound(vSrc) 'skip the header row
    Set cC = New cContributions
    With cC
        .Emp_ID = vSrc(I, 1)
        .PayDate = vSrc(I, 2)
        .Check_Num = vSrc(I, 3)
        .Trans_Type = vSrc(I, 4)
        .Fund_Desc = vSrc(I, 5)
        .Emp_Contrib = vSrc(I, 6)
        .Empr_Contrib = vSrc(I, 7)
        'create a key for uniqueness
        'if there are multiple dates in the source data, could add PayDate to the key
        sKey = .Emp_ID & "|" & .Trans_Type
        colC.Add cC, sKey
        If Err.Number = 457 Then 'combine the data
            Err.Clear
            colC(sKey).Emp_Contrib = colC(sKey).Emp_Contrib + .Emp_Contrib
            colC(sKey).Empr_Contrib = colC(sKey).Empr_Contrib + .Empr_Contrib
        ElseIf Err.Number <> 0 Then
            Debug.Print Err.Number, Err.Description
            Stop  'tells what the error is, but not where it occurred
        End If
    End With
Next I
On Error GoTo 0

'create results array
ReDim vRes(0 To colC.Count, 1 To UBound(vSrc, 2))

'header row
For I = 1 To UBound(vRes, 2)
    vRes(0, I) = vSrc(1, I)
Next I

'data
For I = 1 To colC.Count
    With colC(I)
        vRes(I, 1) = .Emp_ID
        vRes(I, 2) = .PayDate
        vRes(I, 3) = .Check_Num
        vRes(I, 4) = .Trans_Type
        vRes(I, 5) = .Fund_Desc
        vRes(I, 6) = .Emp_Contrib
        vRes(I, 7) = .Empr_Contrib
    End With
Next I

'write and format the data
Set rRes = rRes.Resize(UBound(vRes, 1) + 1, UBound(vRes, 2))

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With rRes
    .EntireColumn.Clear
    .Value = vRes

    'added next line so the 457 would be left aligned.
    'could instead explicitly make it text
    .Columns(5).HorizontalAlignment = xlLeft

    With .Rows(1)
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .Font.Bold = True
    End With
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

---